# Update if present else insert using Morphia in Play framework

Tags: java, mongodb, pojo, morphia, playframework-2.4

Need to update if the document exists else insert it using morphia in play framework. The `save()` or `createIfMissing` methods use `_id`, however I was to test the existence based on another field(say, `customId`). How to achieve this?

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried. It may help seek more attention.

Comment: Not sure who down voted it.

Comment: @BatScream: I have so far used save(Item) with setting the item's _id same as the existing item.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query<entityClazz> q = getDs().createQuery(entityClazz)
                          .field("customId").equal(customId)
                          .get()
UpdateOperations<entityClazz> uop = getDs().createUpdateOperations(entityClazz)                                               .set("name", "XYZ");


getDs().update(query, uop, true);
```

Comment: Is there a was to pass the whole of the item instead of updating each field?